# Priorities of queues with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

With sidekiq is there any configuration for a queue to start only if another one is empty?

I have this configuration and I would like the queue with priority 1 not to be launched until the others have finished. I have thought about how to do it with batches, but as the application is, I don't think it makes sense.

```
:queues:
  - ["tasks", 100]
  - ["products", 80]  
  - ["sellers", 10]
  - ["products", 80]
  - ["seller_types", 1]
```

The issue of priorities in queues is quite improvable ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options):

> If you want queues always processed in a specific order, just declare them in order without weights:
>
> ```
> :queues:
>   - critical
>   - default
>   - low
> ```
>
> This means that any job in the default queue will be processed only when the critical queue is empty.

Comment: Note that the critical jobs may not be **finished** yet when default jobs start, only batches can guarantee job ordering.